# Calculation in List with Duplications

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, duplicates, generic-list

i have a Class like

```
public class user
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public int money { get; set; }

}
```

and Data Like

```
 List<user> users = new List<user>();

        user u1 = new user();
        u1.ID = 1;
        u1.money = 20;
        users.Add(u1);



        user u2 = new user();
        u2.ID = 1;
        u2.money = 30;
        users.Add(u2);



        user u3 = new user();
        u3.ID = 2;
        u3.money = 100;
        users.Add(u3);




        user u4 = new user();
        u4.ID = 2;
        u4.money = 200;
        users.Add(u4);


        user u5 = new user();
        u5.ID = 3;
        u5.money = 500;
        users.Add(u5);
```

**Now i want a list of users which should contains 3 users based on Unique ID and and their Money should be the average according to repetition .**

Any hint would be great in right direction.

Thanks

Comment: I think you can achieve this pretty easily with LINQ using group by ID and avg(money) or something like that, but I've never really used the Group-function in LINQ, so I'm not completely sure how it works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use Linq will be easy, please try:

```
            var q = from u in users
                group u by u.ID into g
                select new user { ID = g.Key, money = (int)g.Average(u => u.money) };

        foreach (user u in q)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("{0}={1}", u.ID, u.money);
        }
```

Answer (score 4):

If I understand you correctly, this should give you what you want - group the users by `ID` and then calculate the average of `money`:

```
var result = from u in users
             group u by u.ID into g
             select new { ID = g.Key, Average = g.Average (x => x.money) };
```

Answer (score 1):

```cs
users.GroupBy(x => x.ID).Select(g => new user() {ID = g.Key, money =(int) g.Average(x => x.money)});
```

Answer (score 1):

If you can't or don't want to use Linq, here's another solution. Also, it looks like you want a weighted average which the other posters seem not to have noticed.

Add a Weight field to the user class with an initial value of 1. Create a dictionary with the user ID's as keys and the user objects as values. Iterate over your 'users' list and:
* check if the dictionary already contains the current user
* if it doesn't, add the user: dict.Add(user.ID, user)
* if it does, increase the weight of that user by 1: dict[user.ID].weight++

After that you can calculate the weighted average pretty easily. Iterate over dict.Values, and add user.money*user.weight to a sum variable in each iteration. After the foreach loop, divide that by the number of unique users:

```
double avg = sum / (double)dict.Count;
```

Don't forget to cast one of the operands to double because otherwise this will be interpreted as an integer division (the remainder will be ignored).

Sorry for the incomplete example and poor formatting but I'm writing this on my phone.